# How can I use mysqli->fetch_all if the PHP version at server is 5.2

Tags: php, mysqli

I have developed a sample in latest PHP 5.3 and have realized it later that justhost dosn't support mysqlnd and PHP 5.3 so I have to change my db class method which are using `mysqli->fetch_all()` .

Does any one know a way to save this effort? Maybe another way arround by using a plugin or middle layer or some thing I can switch or test if mysqlnd is supported at the server or not ?

Comment: Ever thought of using PDO instead? It's pretty standard on all hosts AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest going forward with a database layer like PDO or Zend_Db. Just choose one that you prefer.

Now as far as fixing all your existing code:

1. Most IDE's have some sort of find replace function that can work over multiple files.
2. If you are using OSX/Linux you may want to look at some command line tools like sed to replace the code in your existing files. Might be a bit of a learning curve on that though.

Comment: thanks datasage. i am just thinking how can change mysqli to PDO now

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, Zend_Db is a layer *on top of* PDO. :)

Comment: PDO is one of the options, it supports other adapters as well.